# Are there other ways for creating a file using PHP?

Tags: php

I need to create a series of files and I'm using the following method

```
$file = "myFile.txt";
$fhandle = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($fhandle);
```

Are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: Would it help if you copied the files, or are you just trying to make a group of files by passing in an array?

Comment: Parsing an array with group of files, the names may differ everytime I create files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [touch()](http://php.net/touch) or [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/file_put_contents) with an empty string. These would only require one function call.

Answer (score 4):

```
touch("test.txt");
```

I'm not sure if this will work on non-unix platforms?

Comment: It didn't modify the last-modified time on Windows until PHP 5.3.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
<?php
file_put_contents ($filename , ""); 
?>
```

on a Linux / Unix Server you could use system to do it via a shell command, but I would rather stay with the PHP functions (for Security and portability reasons) - anyway:

```
<?php
system('touch '.escapeshellarg($filename));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [File_Put_Contents](http://www.php.net/file_put_contents) but there isn't any advantage of using that over your method (other than it's shorter).

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your user (typically www-data on Apache servers) has permission to edit the directory that file will exist on.